# Why does this docker image give back this error: Unable to access jarfile /home/server.jar

Tags: docker

```
FROM "this line works but cant show code"

RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64  && yum clean all
COPY /resources/accounts.txt /home/resources/accounts.txt
COPY elk_casino_server /home/elk_casino_server
CMD ["jar","cvmf","/home/elk_casino_server/src/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF","/home/server.jar","/home/elk_casino_server/src/Main.class"]
CMD ["java","-jar","/home/server.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a little more time to format your code snippets correctly and to make sure you ask a clear question.

Your `Dockerfile` uses the `COPY` instruction to copy two resources into your container image:

1. `/resources/accounts.txt` (available within the image at `/home/resources/accounts.txt`)
2. `/elk_casino_server` (available within the image at `/home/elk_casino_server`)

Unfortunately, your `CMD` instructions are trying to execute something very different. Only one command instruction can be defined and the latter will be accepted, which is:

```
CMD ["java","-jar","/home/server.jar"]
```

At no point do you copy `/home/server.jar` into your container image.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter order of the char command seems to be wrong. The `manifest-addition` should come after the `jar-file`, not before it.

```
jar cfm jar-file manifest-addition input-file(s)
```

see: [Packaging Programs in JAR Files: Modifying a Manifest File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html)

---

Also: If there are more than one `CMD`, the last one overrides the others. Since I think you want to pack the jar at build time,  `RUN` might be a better choice.

---

Both points combined:

```
RUN jar cvmf /home/server.jar /home/elk_casino_server/src/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF /home/elk_casino_server/src/Main.class
```